# Error Visual Studio Code and Omnisharp Extension with .Net Core SDK 3.0 preview

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0

How do I fix the error in .Net Core 3.0 project in Visual Studio Code?

I have downloaded the .NET Core 3.0 SDK from created new project with dotnet new command in a folder.

Opening the project with Visual Studio Code gives the following error:

> [fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
>           The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.0.  Either target .NET Core 2.2 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK
>   that supports .NET Core 3.0. [warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
>           Failed to load project file 'c:\Users\Marco\source\Workspaces\WebDevelopment\Samples\hello-world\hello-world.csproj'.
>   c:\Users\Marco\source\Workspaces\WebDevelopment\Samples\hello-world\hello-world.csproj
>   C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.102\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5):
>   Error: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.0. 
>   Either target .NET Core 2.2 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK
>   that supports .NET Core 3.0.
>
> [fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
>           Attemped to update project that is not loaded: c:\Users\Marco\source\Workspaces\WebDevelopment\Samples\hello-world\hello-world.csproj

Comment: Have you installed `.NET Core SDK 3.0.100-preview-010184`? Try to run command `dotnet --version` to see the current sdk. I made a test with VS Code, it opens the project correctly.

Comment: I have installed .NET Core SDK 3.0.100-preview4-010525. Using 2.2.1. is working correctly.

Comment: You should use visual studio and not visual studio code. It is a .net core project, right?

Comment: Do you have visual studio 2019 preview as well? I think you need that. Then make sure any old NuGet packages for an older SDK version uninstalled.

Comment: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0... warning banner shows what relates to my previous comment.

Comment: I did use Visual Studio Code because I do not want to install the preview of Visual Studio 2019. In the past I had problems with different versions of Visual Studio, using Code is to prevent this from happening again.

Answer (score 9):

Not a solution, but a workaround for me :

I have OmniSharp working on Visual code with `.NET CORE 3.0.100-preview3-010431` the trouble seems to come from the version of MSBuild used by `OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator`.

In Visual Code, Look at your OmniSharp Log :

[image]

Not sure that you'll like the solution, but in the OmniShart Log, I read that it was using Visual Studio 2017 MSBuild, and as I met a problem with .net Core Preview 3 project in VS 2017, so I installed Visual Studio Community 2019 RC. My code .NET CORE 3.0 works on VS 2019, but I steel have troubles with OmniSharp in Visual Code. To have it work in visual code I just rename `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MsBuild` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild.disabled`, and all is OK on Visual Code with .NET Core.

```
    Located 3 MSBuild instance(s)
        1: Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 15.9.28307.344 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin"
        2: Visual Studio Community 2019 16.0.28714.193 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
        3: StandAlone 15.0 - "c:\Users\JPB\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.17.1\.omnisharp\1.32.8\msbuild\15.0\Bin"
    Registered MSBuild instance: Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 15.9.28307.344 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin"
```

Becomes :

```
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 2 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: Visual Studio Community 2019 16.0.28714.193 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
            2: StandAlone 15.0 - "c:\Users\JPB\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.csharp-1.17.1\.omnisharp\1.32.8\msbuild\15.0\Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: Visual Studio Community 2019 16.0.28714.193 - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
```

**Conclusion :** Omnisharp seems to need a MSBuild that support .net Core 3.0. I can't find it anywhere else than in VS 2019.

Comment: So how we can build net core 3.x projects without VS2019? Is there any way, other than installing VS2019 (or some part from it) ?

Comment: Have you found a way @psulek? When you use ubuntu you do not have the option of using VS2019

Comment: @CaioGomes i have that error in Windows without VS 2019. So i installed Jetbrains Rider IDE (but it&#39;s not free) and build successfully with it..

Comment: Nice to hear you found a solution. I reverted from dotnet core 3.0 to 2.2 and now its working like a charm. I guess 3.0 its too new for ubuntu yet. I use 3.0 at work with VS2019 on windows and it works fine though.